# export gridview to pdf with header and margin 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, datagrid

i am facing a problem in exporting to PDF since the grid view contain an Arabic text, so i changed my code and it working, the problem is when i export it the gridview header is missing, how can i change the width of the table?, how can i export the same look and feel of the grid view to the PDF, also how can i change the margin of the exported PDF?

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(GridView1.Columns.Count);
        table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR;


        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\\\windows\\\\fonts\\\\tahoma.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        iTextSharp.text.Font f2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);


        for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j <= GridView1.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    string cellText = Page.Server.HtmlDecode(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(100, cellText, f2));

                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }

        }
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);       
        int[] intTblWidth = { 10, 10, 25, 50,25,25,50,10,50,10 };
        table.SetWidths(intTblWidth);
        table.TotalWidth = 500f;
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Page.Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pdfDoc.Add(table); // add the table
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
        Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Page.Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Page.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the link below:

You can set the margin as required

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29759-Exporting-GridView-PDF.aspx

Comment: i already mention the margin and it not affecting the document
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

Comment: check this demo and sample code using iTextSharp freeware PDf library http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/04/how-to-export-gridview-data-to-pdf.html

Comment: i notice that when i use Table the margin is working but in my code i am using PdfPTable and the margin is not working

Answer (score 0):

Also visit the link below....

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-PDF-and-send-PDF-File-as-email-attachment-in-ASPNet.aspx